# Node.js: How to substitute one library with another?

Tags: node.js, module

There's a library `memoize-fs` that uses `fs` package inside. There's a drop-in replacement for `fs` called `graceful-fs` that is a must have when working with a lot of files simulatneously. I'd like to trick `memoize-fs` into using `graceful-fs` without fixing its source code (this approach is obvious). How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using [rewire](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rewire) for this.

```
var rewire = require('rewire');
var memoizefs = require('memoize-fs');
var gracefulfs = rewire('graceful-fs');
gracefulfs.__set__('fs', memoizefs);
```